Two alternate sets of governing equations for inverted pendulum
I've been scratching my head at these two tutorials, which achieve different governing equations for an inverted pendulum on a cart.
M is mass of cart, m is mass of pole, x is position of cart, $ \theta $ is angular position of pole, and $ F_u $ is a force applied horizontally to the cart, L is length to center of mass of pole.
The first (for a point mass) makes sense to me. Using the horizontal cart forces and horizontal and vertical pendulum forces, we get
$$ -mg\sin\theta = m\ddot{x}\cos\theta - mL\ddot{\theta} \tag{Equation A}$$
$$F_u + mL\ddot{\theta}\cos\theta - mL\dot{\theta}^2\sin\theta = (M + m)\ddot{x} \tag{Equation B}$$
The second (for a rod) also gets our Equation B (see it's equation 3), but never gets Equation A. Instead, it gets
$$(I + mL^2)\ddot{\theta} + mgL\sin\theta = -mL\ddot{x}\cos\theta \tag{Equation C}$$
Here are my two confusions:
Confusion A: The moment of inertia for a point mass is $mL^2$, and the moment of inertia for a rod is $\frac{4mL^2}{3}$ (4 because our L is not the length of the pole, but half). If we were to plug in our point mass inertia into Equation C, we would get
$$-mg\sin\theta = m\ddot{x}\cos\theta + 2mL\ddot{\theta} \tag{Equation D}$$
I'm not too worried about the swapped negative signs, but Equation D has $ 2mL\ddot{\theta} $, while Equation A has $ mL\ddot{\theta} $. Which one is right?
Confusion B: Equation 4 relates the forces and masses & accelerations along the axis perpendicular to the pendulum. However, it includes $P\sin\theta + N\cos\theta$. Shouldn't these sum to 0? These are the forces that are delivered through the "stick", which is perpendicular to the axis we are writing equations for. Is there some inertial force or something that only applies to the rod case, and not the point mass case?


You say "inverted pendulum" but then also mention a cart.  I guess the pendulum is pivoted on the cart and the cart can move horizontally?  And I guess $\theta$ is the pendulum angle and $x$ is the cart position?  And $m$ is the pendulum mass and $M$ is the cart mass? If the question is clear, readers shouldn't have to guess.  A diagram would be helpful, almost required I would say.

Thanks @MarianoG, I added variable labels and a diagram.

Also FYI the moment of inertia of a rod about its center is $\frac{1}{12}mL^2$.  But the moment of inertia of a rod about its end is $\frac{1}{3}mL^2$.

I'll derive equation from scratch for the rod, using a Lagrangian mechanics approach.
Lagrangian function, $\mathscr{L} = T-V$, is the difference of the kinetic energy and the potential energy. Choosing the coordinate $x$ of the cart along the horizontal direction, and the angle $\theta$ of the rod with respect to the vertical direction as the the 2 generalized coordinates, the kinetic energy reads
$$\begin{aligned}
  T & = \dfrac{1}{2} \left[ M \dot{x}^2 + m|\mathbf{v}_G|^2 +  I_G \dot{\theta}^2  \right] = \\ 
& = \dfrac{1}{2} \left[ M \dot{x}^2 + m\left( \left( \dot{x} + \frac{L}{2} \dot{\theta} \cos \theta \right)^2 + \left( \frac{L}{2} \dot{\theta} \sin \theta \right)^2 \right) +  \frac{1}{12} m L^2 \dot{\theta}^2  \right] = \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \left[ (M+m) \dot{x}^2 + m L\dot{x} \dot{\theta} \cos\theta + \left( \dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac{1}{12} \right) m L^2 \dot{\theta}^2 \right],
\end{aligned}$$
$G$ being the center of mass of the rod, $\mathbf{v}_G$ its velocity, and $I_G$ the moment of inertia with respect to $G$. The potential energy is
$$V = m g \frac{L}{2} \cos \theta.$$
The Euler-Lagrange equations, are
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial \dot{q}} \right) - \frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial {q}} = Q_q ,$$
give
$$(M+m) \ddot{x} + m \frac{L}{2} \ddot{\theta} \cos \theta - m \frac{L}{2} \dot{\theta}^2 \sin \theta = F$$
$$\frac{1}{3} m L^2 \ddot{\theta} +\frac{1}{2 } m L \ddot{x} \cos \theta \underbrace{-\frac{1}{2 } m L \dot{x} \dot{\theta} \sin \theta +\frac{1}{2 } m L \dot{x} \dot{\theta} \sin \theta}_{=0} - m g \frac{L}{2} \sin \theta = 0 .$$
The first equation is the balance of the momentum of the whole system in the horizontal direction. The second equation is the balance of the angular momentum of the rod with respect to its hinge.
Confusion B: what you say is true only for massless rods, that can only hold axial loads (by rotation equilibrium of the element without inertia). Once you've solved the dynamical equation, you can find these reactions from dynamical equilibrium equations. As an example, using the horizontal and the vertical components of the momentum equation of the rod
$$\begin{aligned}
 & m \dfrac{d}{dt} \left( \dot{x} + \frac{L}{2} \dot{\theta} \cos \theta \right) = N \\
 & m \dfrac{d}{dt} \left( - \frac{L}{2} \dot{\theta} \sin \theta \right) = P - m g.
\end{aligned}$$

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
